# Entity Framework uses nvarchar (max) when MaxLength is specified

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have specified a text field's `MaxLength` as 4096 with EF fluent api in order to limit its length:

```
this.Property(p => p.MyText).HasMaxLength(4096).IsRequired();
```

But for some reason in SQL Server, the column becomes `nvarchar (max)`.

Just for test if I specify 2048 to make sure that SQL Server gets updated

```
this.Property(p => p.MyText).HasMaxLength(2048).IsRequired();
```

And this way it is works.

So my queston why EF sets sql `nvarchar (max)` when `MaxLength(4096)`

Comment: As long as your `nvarchar` column is **less than 4000** characters (2 bytes each) - SQL Server will use the `nvarchar(n)` type. The upper limit is **4000** characters - if you specify a length greater than that, there's no alternative but to use `nvarchar(max)` (which supports up to **1 billion** characters)

Comment: @marc_s That seems ridiculous (I know it's not your fault; I'm just responding to your comment).  There's a HUGE amount of space between 4000 and 2^31 - 1.  Why can't I specify 8192 or something?  I'm wondering if there's a technical reason for it, or if they just decided, "if you need more than 4000 (which is itself arbitrary), then max will just have to do".

Comment: @AriRoth: the physical storage in SQL Server is organized in **pages** which are 8K (8192 bytes). Since `nvarchar` always uses 2 bytes per character, and each page has a few header bytes, you basically get 8000 bytes (or 4000 `nvarchar` characters) on a single page - at most. Therefore, the "normal" `nvarchar(n)` is limited to a max. of 4000 chars (the non-Unicode `varchar(n)` is limited to 8000 chars). If you need more, then you get a total of 2 GB of storage through pretty elaborate (and complicated) structures of using 8K pages to store all that data

Comment: @marc_s Oh yeah, I forgot about the 8k page size.  It just seems weird to me that nvarchar basically says "You can limit the field size to 8k, but after that you're just going to have to use max".  I mean, this seems like a solvable problem, and I imagine there are plenty of cases where you'd want to limit the field size to more than 4000 characters and less than max.  But I'm not a DB admin or anything, so maybe it's not as solvable as it seems it would be to me. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's SQL Server limits. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx) says

> Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through **4,000**.